# Python ImportError: No module named 'path'

Tags: python

```
''' Data class'''

import os.path
from random import Random

class TestData(object, Random):

    def FetchDataFromFile(self, filename):
        """ Open the file as read only """
        myfile = open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),filename), 'r')
        """ read the information in the file """
        lines = myfile.read()
        ''' Remove the header as this will not be used '''
        header = lines[0] 
        lines.remove(header)
        return lines
```

I am getting:

> ImportError: No module named path
>
> File "**pyclasspath**/Lib/Testdata.py", line 2, in

os.path is working in all other classes in my project. Can someone point me what mistake i am doing?

I moved this file from one directory to another. Apart from it, there is no difference between this class and other classes.

Comment: You could do `from os import path` but I think the preferred way is `import os` and then use `os.path.method_name()` in your script.

Comment: @squiguy if he use `from os import path`, he need use `path` instead of `os.path`

Comment: do you have a file in there named `os.py`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`import os` should work fine instead

```
import os
from random import Random

class TestData(object, Random):

    def FetchDataFromFile(self, filename):
        """ Open the file as read only """
        myfile = open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),filename), 'r')
        """ read the information in the file """
        lines = myfile.read()
        ''' Remove the header as this will not be used '''
        header = lines[0] 
        lines.remove(header)
        return lines
```

as an asside your method could be

```
def FetchDataFromFile(self, filename):
        """ Open the file as read only """
        return list(open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),filename), 'r'))[1:]
```

Comment: Congrats on getting 10K rep.

Comment: Okay. I found the error. The destination folder name was Lib. I had to change it to some other name, Library, and it started working again. Thanks for your suggestion too.

Comment: but `import os.path as op` is valid

Answer (score 2):

I had the package name in the project as 'Lib' and moved the Testdata module into the Lib. 
I guess Python didn't like the package name. Renamed it to Library and now its working. The error is not related to the import statement. Both import os.path AND from os import path works fine.